# Problem Installing Ubuntu- hangs at preparation

Tags: installation, 12.10, dual-boot, partitioning, mac

I have read that this problem usually is in result of my partition not being clean?  I believe I have a failed installation that may be causing trouble but not sure. Here is what my partitions look like as of now. Setting aside the 40GB partition for Ubuntu.

[image: screenshot from gparted]

If you could suggest a few steps I would appreciate it!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have enough free space on any of those partitions.
Sda2 and Sda3 used by your other Operating System.

You have 3 options:

1. Move whatever resides on sda3 to sda2 and then delete sda3 and use it for ubuntu installation. might be the best option as it seems you only have 149MB worth of content in it, though i might be wrong and in some weird way it's a system partition ;)?
2. You can try to shrink sda2 or sda3 and then use the newly free space for Ubuntu installation.
3. Get another HDD and use it for ubuntu installation.

Comment: how do I make sda3 usable for my ubuntu installation.  I made that partition off of sda2 through mac osx diskutility.  Should I revert the partition and try in gparted? Although not very savvy with gparted.

Comment: You can do that easily through Gparted, just right click on sda3 and choose delete. Please take care to backup whatever is in sda3 before doing so. after you delete sda3, you'll have an unallocated space of about 40GB, use it while installing ubuntu to make 2 partitions also called "Mount points": 1. for root aka "/". 2. for home aka "/home". make sure to use "ext4" file system.

Comment: okay thank you, I thought the delete option was going to remove the partition.  After deleting it turned to unallocated space and am now installing. Will update.

Comment: So it seems to have installed successfully.  I chose "install alongside mac os," I didn't create the 2 partitions that you suggested, I believe it made something along the lines automatically, is there a difference?

Comment: In this case, Ubuntu automatically allocated space for the installation. Enjoy your new OS.